# Print a stack trace to stdout on errors in Django while using manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

I did some searching, but I'm wondering if anyone has a snippet of a logging configuration to get Django to just output a stack trace to stdout (so I can see it in the Terminal window) when it encounters an error during a request. This is specifically for local development/debugging and mainly for when I do AJAX post requests and I have to look at the HTML in Firebug to figure out what line the error occurred on.

Comment: "Terminal Window"?  You're running `django-admin.py runserver`?

Comment: Yes, `manage.py runserver` locally, but this would be helpful for production as well, although there I get emails, so less of an issue.

Comment: the "production" approach depends on how you're integrated with Apache, so you'll need to provide yet more details on that configuration to be sure we understand.

Comment: @SLott Good point, for now I'll edit the question to be specifically about local development. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create a piece of middleware to do this. Here's a modified snippet I'm using for a project:

```
class ExceptionLoggingMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        import traceback
        print traceback.format_exc()
```

Place this handler in your middleware part of the Django settings.

Comment: The format for these exceptions have changed since this answer (understandably!). The updated format can be seen at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233213/366529

Answer (score 38):

Another method is with *LOGGING*. Specifically you get a stacktrace when running `./manage.py runserver` by adding the following to the *settings.py* file:

```python
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        }
    },
}
```

This syntax comes from the Django documentation [Configuring Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) and can be further modified to increase or decrease the amount of console-logging.

Also the *5XX* responses are raised as ERROR messages and *4XX* responses are raised as WARNING messages.

Note that this question & answer has a 2013 duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833195/stack-trace-from-manage-py-runserver-not-appearing/23818289#23818289).

Comment: This should be the preferred method in my opinion. You have far more control over what loggers you want to use, what you want to log etc.

Comment: By far the cleanest solution. I'd recommend that this answer is flagged as the final answer.

Comment: Finally what I was looking for!

Answer (score 28):

It's strange nobody mentioned the [`DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#debug-propagate-exceptions) setting. It's not for production, but very easy to use for at test/debugging environment. Simply add to `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

Comment: Exactly this seems the most appropriate answer :)

Comment: +1 for what is worth, after a couple of hours debugging a DRF issue and with no more tests/options to try, you literally saved my day...

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer, thank you so much!

Comment: What's the difference between this and using the LOGGING json item in the other answer?

Comment: @Jay with LOGGING you might turn on a lot of log messages from various spots in application. In production setting, this is apparently the most correct approach. But for quick and dirty debugging having only exceptions printed to a console should do.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but the middleware option didn't help me. The reason is that I'm using django-jsonview 0.4.3 which provides a decorator that converts a dictionary into a valid json http response, even when the decorated function fails, so process_exception middleware method is never called. I checked the code of this decorator and it seems that it tries to log the error doing this:

```
...
except Exception as e:
    logger = logging.getLogger('django.request')
    logger.exception(unicode(e))
```

However, I don't know why, this is not working and nothing is logged in my bash console. I should find out why this in happening. Meanwhile, I'm using an extra decorator:

```
def log_errors(func):
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        return func

    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print traceback.format_exc()
    return wrapper
```

Then, in all my json views:

```
@json_view
@log_errors
def my_view(request):
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this:

```
    except Exception,e:
        # Get line
        trace=traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
        # Add the event to the log
        output ="Error in the server: %s.\n" % (e)
        output+="\tTraceback is:\n"
        for (file,linenumber,affected,line)  in trace:
            output+="\t> Error at function %s\n" % (affected)
            output+="\t  At: %s:%s\n" % (file,linenumber)
            output+="\t  Source: %s\n" % (line)
        output+="\t> Exception: %s\n" % (e)
```

Then I use "**output**" for whatever I need: print to stdout, send an email, etc...

Comment: I think there are better answers here, but it's also worth pointing out that you might as well just call `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` instead of these many lines.

Comment: In your way you are not able to do anything with the the exception, so I still prefer mine because is more flexible and is an example of working with: filename, line number and line of code which produced the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass WSGI handler, do whatever you want with traceback in your defined `handle_uncaught_exception`, and use your WSGIHandler instead of the one provided by django when deploying.

```
import traceback
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

class MyWSGIHandler(WSGIHandler):
    """WSGI Handler which prints traceback to stderr"""
    def handle_uncaught_exception(self, request, resolver, exc_info):
        traceback.print_tb(exc_info[2], file=sys.stderr)
        return super(WSGIHandler, self).handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)
```

Used with Apache/mod_wsgi, this should write traceback in Apache's error log